# Write error Collection into an excel file in Selenium Java

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, console

I am using Selenium Java for automating my project.
In this I have used an ArrayList where we are adding all the errors we face during automation. My code looks something like below:

```
List<String> errorCollection = new ArrayList<String>();
errorCollection.add("Machine "+machine+" not found for line:"+line);
```

Like above, I have numerous errors that I have added in the array list and I am printing the same on my console.

Next what I am trying to do is, I want to write all these errors that I am showing on console in an excel.

What can be done to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried in order to write your results to excel and whet problems have you faced with?

Comment: Please always provide code sample including exceptions or stacktrace.

Comment: I am new to this, so I have not tried any specific script to write console output to excel. Any links to start with would be helpful.

Comment: See https://blog.knoldus.com/read-and-write-data-from-excel-sheet-using-apache-poi/ or full tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/index.htm